# iOS dark gray box active style

Tags: css, ios, mobile-safari

When touching a link or anything with an onclick event in mobile safari a dark gray box appears over the element. What is this called and what CSS selector can I use to get rid of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's the -webkit-tap-highlight-color. Here's a little extra info for you:

http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-tap-highlight-color

```
/* webkit-tap-highlight-color */
a:link { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #aa0000; }

/* To set it to none use a totally transparent RGBA */
a:link { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
```

You can also check out the [Safari Mobile developer docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html) to see the supported CSS properties.

Comment: It really saves my day