# iOS Safari Mobile image map - area displays box when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, ios, mobile-safari, area

So, this one seems to be a little tricky. There's an image map with some areas and the function is like:

- click on an area, display a tooltip

Here's some code (just a snippet):

```
<img src="content/dummy/1_small.jpg" alt="" usemap="#img_1">
<map name="img_1">
    <area shape="rect" coords="150,50,250,150" href="" alt="" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="250,500,350,600" href="" alt="" />
</map>
```

And the according click handler:

```
this.areas.click( function (event) {
    var position    = that.areas.index(event.target);
    that.toggleTooltipTouch(position);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Which works fine. But: Whenever I click on an area, Safari displays a little, slightly transparent box for the time of the touch event. If you hit it very short, it looks like it's flickering.

So, the question is: How to prevent this behavior and don't show that box?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you mean but maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009377/ios-dark-gray-box-active-style

Comment: Absolutely, that's what I meant. Yeah. Didn't know how to put this in words, that's why I didn't find any solution. :) Could you post your link as an answer? Than I can accept it and "end" the question. Or is there another way of doing hat? :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [iOS dark gray box active style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009377/ios-dark-gray-box-active-style) you have to hide the tap highlight box:

```
img { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
```